# Corresponding graphql-tag for a schema with nested inputs?

Tags: apollo, graphql-js, react-apollo, graphcool

I'm following a tutorial (here:https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/5-authentication/) on graphql and came across a mutation with nested inputs.
How would I write the corresponding graphql-tag?

```
gql``
```

Schema:

```
type Mutation {
  createUser(name: String!, authProvider: AuthProviderSignupData!): User
}
###########
## Inputs
###########

input AuthProviderEmail {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

input AuthProviderSignupData {
  email: AuthProviderEmail
}
```

Corresponding graphiql input:

```
mutation CreateUser {
  createUser(name: "tester2", authProvider: {email: {email: "test@test.com", password: "password"}}) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const mutation = gql`
   mutation createUser($authProvider: AuthProviderSignupData!, $name: String!) {
     createUser(authProvider: $authProvider, name: $name) {
       id
     }
   }
`

const variables = {
    "authProvider": {
      "email": {
         "email": "chakri@example.com",
          "password": "123456789"
         }
      },
     "name": "chakri",      
    }
```

Comment: I don't know how to select your answer as the correct one; however, I do want to clarify that your answer is what I'm looking for but is missing the $name part to be completely correct.  Thank you!

Comment: what is AuthProviderSignupData ? is it just a simple string or do declare it some where